# Infinite coin toss sequence

Tags: probability, puzzle

Two players $A$ and $B$ are flipping a coin. $A$ starts with $6$ points and $B$ has $4$ points. They flip a coin and if it’s a head, then $A$ gets a point from $B$. If it’s a tail, then $B$ gets a point from $A$. What’s the probability that $A$ is the first to $10$ points?

The answer is $\frac{6}{10}$, which can be verified by numerical simulation. To get this result mathematically it is also clear that we can consider the combinations in an infinite sequence as:

$$ P(A_{\text{wins}}) = \sum_{i} (\frac{1}{2})^{2i + 4} \cdot {2i + 4 \choose i } $$

However the source where I found this questions also states that the result can be obtained straightforwardly by symmetry arguments - by observing that the players have equal probability of winning if the first toss is a tail, since in this case on the second toss each player would have $5$ points and be equally likely to reach $10$ first.

Although I can see this is true, I can't see how to arrive at the probability of $\frac{6}{10}$ of an $A-\text{win}$ from this starting point - can anyone see what the necessary further arguments are?

Comment: This is the standard [Gambler's Ruin Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin).

Comment: How much do you know about Markov chains and/or martingales?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I'm reasonably familiar with MCs from the point of view of numerical simulations

Comment: @lulu so would the reasoning be that the two players are in an equilibrium with each other, so their probabilities of reaching 10 first are proportional to their distance from 10?

Comment: That sounds vague to me.  The usual arguments start by introducing $P(n)$, the probability that $A$ eventually wins given that they currently hold $n$ coins (so you want $P(6)$).  Then remark that $P(9)=\frac 12+\frac 12\times P(8)$, and generally, $P(n)=\frac 12\times P(n+1)+\frac 12\times P(n-1)$, $P(0)=0$, and solve that system (it's pretty easy).

Comment: But, really, the Gambler's Ruin is one of the most written about problems in all of probability. [here's](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/FE-Notes/4700-07-Notes-GR.pdf) another reference, and you can easily find many more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with Markov chains, then you must be made familiar with a few concepts , with the help of which we can write a theorem and use it to solve this problem. Our theorem is referred to as $\color{green}{\mathit{first\  step\  analysis}}$.

---

A "stopping time" of the Markov chain, is a function from the "path space" to time, which tells us when to stop the chain, and observe its results. For example, you could create a Markov chain out of coin tosses (heads and tails), and ask to stop when you get three consecutive heads.

Now, you could observe a "function of the current state" at a stopping time. For example, when you choose to stop, you could look if you belong in a "good set" of  states or a "bad" set of states. For example if you are gambling and stop after some time, a "good" set of states would be those for which you've gained money, and bad for which you've lost money.

First step analysis deals specifically with the question : Let $f(x)$ be the expected value of a state function at a stopping time, given I start at the state $x$. Can I calculate $f(x)$? Indeed, it turns out that $f(x)$ depends on $f(x')$ for some other states $x'$ : this gives rise to a sequence of equations which can be solved.

---

In our case, we have the Markov chain as the set of all states of the game. Let $(a,b)$ mean that $A$ has $a$ points and $B$ has $b$ points. Then, since $a+b = 10$, we have the state space $\{(0,10),(1,9),(2,8),...,(9,1),(10,10)\}$.

On this , we define the stopping time as : stop when either you hit $(0,10)$ or if you hit $(10,0)$. We also define the function of state $f(x)$ as the probability that you hit $(0,10)$ before you hit $(10,0)$.

You could also write this as follows : if the function $g(y)$ is $1$ at $(10,0)$ and $0$ elsewhere, then the expected value of $g$ given you start at $x$, is $f(x)$. (Figure this out yourself).

---

According to first step analysis, we "step forward and look at how we reach the stopping time now". Let us take a simple example : suppose I want to find the probability that from $(9,1)$ I reach $(10,0)$ before $(0,10)$. Now, look at the next step : with probability $\frac 12$, I hit $(10,0)$ so I reach $(10,0)$, so now the probability of reaching $(10,0)$ before $(0,10)$ is $f((10,0)) = 1$ (obviously). On the other hand, I could hit $(8,2)$ with probability $\frac 12$ : then the probability of reaching $(10,0)$ before $(0,10)$ is $f((8,2))$.

In other words :
$$
f((9,1)) = \frac{f(10,0) + f(8,2)}{2} = \frac{1 + f(8,2)}{2}
$$

we can very similarly write :
$$
f((x,10-x)) = \frac{f((x+1,10-x-1)) + f(x-1,10-x+1)}{2}
$$

along with $f(10,0) = 1$ and $f(0,10) = 0$. Ten equations, ten unknowns, but we know the pattern : look up "gambler's ruin" to see a generalization of this phenomena, along with how to solve this kind of equation.